# What's the simplest way to import an SQLite SQL file into a WEB SQL Database

Tags: sql, sqlite, safari, local-storage

perhaps I'm missing something, but I need a client side database pre-populated with a load of data.

To test whether client side databases were up to the task, I created a few dummy tables with dummy data using the `transaction.executeSql()` method. But from what I can gather, it requires an executeSQL call for every single CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO query. I'm lazy, and that seems like too much work to me.

I'm wondering...: I can create an SQLite table fairly quickly using an SQLite GUI. I've tried exporting an SQL file and running it all in one executeSQL statement but that just processes the first 'CREATE TABLE' bit none of the inserts.

Is there some special method of the transaction object that I'm not aware of for running multiple queries at once?

This is for Mobile Safari buy the way, which [according to Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/RelationalDatabases/RelationalDatabases.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007256-CH5-SW2) uses an SQLite Database to power their client side database stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i put all the sql code into a file with one command per line then used ajax to pull file and loop over each line executing the sql

tip: use the if not exists so you can call it every time to init your database

Comment: Please, can you provide some pieces of code? I have the same problem and cannot load an sql script file into an web sql database created on the fly.

Answer (score 16):

On the commandline (in a linux box), use

```
sqlite3 myDatabase.sqlite .dump > myDatabase.sql
```

Now you have the sqlite file dumped to a plain sql file. It will contain the create table statements and the insert statements.

Then, some clientside code (will probably need some adjusting, but you'll get the idea)

First, grab the sql dump. (example using jQuery)

```
$.get('./dumps/myDatabase.sql', function(response) {
  // console.log("got db dump!", response);
  var db = openDatabase('myDatabase', '1.0', 'myDatabase', 10000000);
  processQuery(db, 2, response.split(';\n'), 'myDatabase'); 
});
```

The processQuery function process all the statements one by one, and silently ignores errors.

```
function processQuery(db, i, queries, dbname) {
    if(i < queries.length -1) {
      console.log(i +' of '+queries.length);
      if(!queries[i+1].match(/(INSERT|CREATE|DROP|PRAGMA|BEGIN|COMMIT)/)) {
        queries[i+1] = queries[i]+ ';\n' + queries[i+1];
         return processQuery(db, i+1, queries, dbname);
      }
      console.log('------------>', queries[i]);
      db.transaction( function (query){ 
        query.executeSql(queries[i]+';', [], function(tx, result) {
          processQuery(db, i +1, queries,dbname);  
        });          
      }, function(err) { 
      console.log("Query error in ", queries[i], err.message);                          
      processQuery(db, i +1, queries, dbname);   
      });
  } else {
      console.log("Done importing!");
  }
}
```