# Injecting sql scripts from an SQL file into sqlite database in javascript

Tags: sqlite, import, sql-scripts

I have an html page that creates an sqlite database using the `openDatabase` function.

As I have an existing and large sqlite database, I wonder if I can import it into that web created sqlite database instead of putting my sql code in the `transaction.executeSql` function repeatedly?

PS: I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834534/whats-the-simplest-way-to-import-an-sqlite-sql-file-into-a-web-sql-database) but no code is shown and the method explained isn't so clear.

Thanks,

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if I've understood the question right... but here's something which may or may not answer your question (works in Google Chrome, not sure about anything else):

```
var db = openDatabase(dbname);
db.transaction(function (query){
   query.executeSql(sql);
});
```

But you mentioned "web created"... does that mean with a server-side script like PHP? It sounds to me like you have the SQL necessary to import into the database, so why not just create a page with a text box that will let you paste the SQL in, and then post it to the db. If that's in PHP, then it would look something like this:

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
  <textarea name="query"></textarea />
  <input type="text" name="password" />
  <input type="submit />
</form>

<?
if ($_POST['password']=="my super secure password")
{
  $dbname='base';
  $mytable ="tablename";

  $base= new SQLiteDatabase($dbname);
  $base->queryexec($_POST['query']);
}
?>
```

It shouldn't be too hard to come up with an equivalent in any other language. If you need help, you know where to ask! ;)

Comment: The problem is that I have an HTML page ... I can create an sqlite database with javascript. But, I found no javascript function can read an existing database.

Comment: Not possible. You need some sort of server script to supply the information to the browser.