# Access database on offline mobile

Tags: android, sql-server, html, mobile, web-sql

I want to copy my mssql database onto my phone so that I can access it with my hybrid app for android and I can work offline if net is unavailable.

What is the simplest way to do this? Is web sql the solution or should I look somewhere else?

Comment: you have to use sqlite database to copy data from mysql to sqlite.

Comment: But I am not making a native app. I am making a hybrid app with html5 and javascript. I will pack this with phonegap. Do I still have to use sqllite?? Can you give me links to some tutorials and guide me in general?

Answer (score 0):

`WebSQL` or `LocalStorage` is a good choice to store data as both are supported by multiple mobile platforms.

As you have to copy from a MySQL DB then WebSQL would be the right choice. Though there are limitations in maximum size of the DB.

This Link might help you:
[What's the simplest way to import an SQLite SQL file into a WEB SQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834534/whats-the-simplest-way-to-import-an-sqlite-sql-file-into-a-web-sql-database)

Comment: Can you help me out here plz. Don't have much idea how to do it i.e transfer a database to websql